# why is my php str_replace function not working inside a mysql while

Tags: php, html, mysql, escaping

I have a function like this:

```
function remove_chars($string)
    {
        $string = @stripslashes($string);

        $string = str_ireplace("'","&#039;",$string);
        $string = str_ireplace('"','&quot;',$string);

        return trim($string);
    }
```

That I then use in the mySQL result like this below:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$name = remove_chars($row['name']);

// ...
echo "<td width=\"100%\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"name[]\" value=\"".$name."\" 
style=\"width:100%;\" /></td>";
// ...

}
```

But that's not working. The special characters are still displaying and therefor also messing up the code. Any ideas why?

Comment: No idea, but use `htmlspecialchars` instead. That's what it's for.

Comment: Use single quotes for string encapsulation then you don't need to escape every double quote for the attribute values. What does the generated source come out as?

Comment: Please **do not** arbitrarily use the YOLO operator `@`. That suppresses errors. Additionally, `stripslashes` is not going to help you here. As @rjdown says, [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is the proper way to escape for the HTML context.

Comment: @tadman: Unless they double escaped before insert.

Comment: @AbraCadaver If that's the case the solution is to remove the escaping in the database. It is never to remove slashes in the view. Clean up the mess, don't make it worse.